# You can't use a prefix with `\char"FB': error when importing csv into latex

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

I'm trying to use the package csvsimple to create a table from a csv file. This worked so far, but when I try to add new figures/tables afterwards I get multiple errors. It looks like the \end statement of my table is not properly recognized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm,textheight=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
\csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\\hline]{myCSV.csv}{}{\count & \columnii & \columniii}
\end{tabular}
\caption{myCaption}
\label{tbl:top40}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
% any figure here
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following error messages:

```
./test2.tex:22: You can't use a prefix with `\char"FB'. [\end]
./test2.tex:22: Missing number, treated as zero. [\end]
./test2.tex:22: Improper \prevdepth. [\end{figure}]
./test2.tex:22: You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode. [\end{figure}]
./test2.tex:22: Missing number, treated as zero. [\end{figure}]
./test2.tex:22: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\end{figure}]
./test2.tex:24: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost. [\end{document}]
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a small CSV file that produces the error?

Comment: I just found the error myself. I had a column name called \count (instead of \coli as in my example above). As soon as I changed the \count to something like \countFoo it would work.

Is \count a protected keyword? Just curious. I'm not able to find anything related to that keyword.

Comment: Note that `\count` is a fundamental primitive command of TeX; using it in the column name redefines it, which is not a good idea! `;-)` If you add the small example, the question can still be useful for other readers; you can even self-answer it.

Comment: Yep, it's too bad latex wouldn't give me an error warning that is related to the changing of a primitive. Thanks for your help anyway! I changed the code in the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I add this answer for other readers which may have the same problem in the future.

The cause of the problem is the redefinition of a fundamental primitive command of TeX as egreg commented. This was done by `head to column names`. This option maps the heading contents to macro names. If a macro is existing, it becomes redefined. Here, the `\count` macro was redefined.

If the critical name of the heading cannot be changed inside the CSV file, one should not use `head to column names`. One can do the following:

**1. Default names:**

The columns can be addressed by default macro names `\csvcoli`, `\csvcolii`, etc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{myCSV.csv}
count,columnii,columniii
alpha,beta,gamma
blue,red,green
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
\csvreader[late after line=\\\hline]{myCSV.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{tabular}
\caption{myCaption}
\label{tbl:top40}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
% any figure here
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**2. Define own macro names (A):**

One can define own macro names like `count=\mycount` to address the count column by `\mycount`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{myCSV.csv}
count,columnii,columniii
alpha,beta,gamma
blue,red,green
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
\csvreader[late after line=\\\hline]{myCSV.csv}{
    count=\mycount,columnii=\mytwo,columniii=\mythree}
  {\mycount & \mytwo & \mythree}
\end{tabular}
\caption{myCaption}
\label{tbl:top40}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
% any figure here
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**3. Define own macro names (B):**

One can define own macro names like `1=\mycount` to address the first column by `\mycount`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{myCSV.csv}
count,columnii,columniii
alpha,beta,gamma
blue,red,green
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
\csvreader[late after line=\\\hline]{myCSV.csv}{
    1=\mycount,2=\mytwo,3=\mythree}
  {\mycount & \mytwo & \mythree}
\end{tabular}
\caption{myCaption}
\label{tbl:top40}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
% any figure here
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```